# How to show same camera video in two views

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am trying to show the same camera video in two different views; However I only get the video in one view. Could you help. Code is below

```
-(void) showCameraPreview{
    self.camerPreviewCaptureSession =[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    self.camerPreviewCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput1 = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    [self.camerPreviewCaptureSession addInput:videoInput1];
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoViewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.camerPreviewCaptureSession];
    newCaptureVideoViewLayer.frame = self.viewPreview.bounds;
    newCaptureVideoViewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [newCaptureVideoViewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.viewPreview.bounds.size.width, self.viewPreview.bounds.size.height )];

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCameraViewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.camerPreviewCaptureSession];
    newCameraViewLayer.frame = self.viewPreview1.bounds;
    newCameraViewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [newCameraViewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.viewPreview1.bounds.size.width, self.viewPreview1.bounds.size.height )];

    [self.viewPreview1.layer addSublayer:newCameraViewLayer];
    [self.viewPreview.layer addSublayer:newCaptureVideoViewLayer];

    [self.camerPreviewCaptureSession startRunning];
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting in log ?

Comment: I don't get any errors in log.